# How to find out Bluez version from command line?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am using some custom Linux distribution without any UI. I would like to find out the Bluez version through the command-line. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a rough idea (or are fine with covering the last 10 years), `bluez` provides tools in `bluez-uils` to request the version. Unfortunately, these tools changed between version 4 and 5, so you may have to check if one of both is installed.

For BlueZ 4.0:

```
bluetoothd --version
```

Since BlueZ 5.0, there is a new command-line tool `bluetoothctl`:

```
bluetoothctl --version
```

Answer (score 3):

Bluez provides a shared library called libbluetooth.so. On x86_64 distros you should find this file in `/usr/lib64/`, so simply do a `ls -la` to find out

```
$ls -la /usr/lib64/libbluetooth.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 17 12:44 /usr/lib64/libbluetooth.so -> libbluetooth.so.3.17.0
```

In my case, I'm using version `3.17.0`

`readelf(1)` can also provide some information as well.

Comment: I doubt this. Going back the history on Arch or http://www.bluez.org, a Bluez version 3.17 would be more than 10 years old.

Answer (score 2):

On my distribution (Fedora 21), you can find it in  `/usr/share/doc/bluez/ChangeLog.` You might try reading it with `less` or simliar.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the `bluetoothd -v` command in the command line. It gives the bluez version installed in your target.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using systemd, you can get the BlueZ version running, using `systemctl`:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

It will output something like this:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-25 13:00:52 UTC; 14min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 471 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
        └─471 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 25 13:00:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 25 13:00:52 raspberrypi bluetoothd[471]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jul 25 13:00:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 25 13:00:52 raspberrypi bluetoothd[471]: Starting SDP server
Jul 25 13:00:52 raspberrypi bluetoothd[471]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

This way you can be 100% sure that you are running the right version.